# Index and complementary index, in a Matlab array

Tags: matlab

Here I have an array and extract some elements according to a conditional statement;

```
A = 10:-1:1;
idx = find(A>3);
```

What is the direct way to get the rest of elements, which are here 1, 2 and 3, but using returned idx ?

Comment: `idx = find(A <= 3);`?

Comment: True, just I thought there if there is any way to get index of elements and the rest all in one line, something like [idx, rest] = ...

Comment: You can't. You have to write an additional line of code to do that. `find` only finds indices that satisfy the Boolean condition as its input. It doesn't support finding those that don't satisfy the condition as well simultaneously.

Comment: ok, I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is complementary to the other answers. You can go through the array A only once. I would prefer boolean indexing to do so:

```
idx1 = A>3;
idx2 = ~idx1;
```

You could do a similar game with the indices that find returns:

```
idx1 = find(A>3)
idx2 = setdiff(1:length(A), idx1); % assuming A is a vector
```

Answer (score 3):

i wouldnt go as far as using 'find' if it is just about the conditional statement.
you can use:

```
X=A(A>3) %for the conditional Elements or
Y=A(~(A>3)) % for the other group
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply change the ">" sign to "<=":

```
idx = find(A<=3);
```

You can also use a boolean inverse:

```
idx = find(~(A>3));
```